# Which of the possible monetary policy channels is there empirical evidence for?

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, interest-rate, money-supply, academic-graduate

There are many possible monetary policy channels. These channels are the different ways that changes in the Fed's interest rates can affect the economy: exchange rate depreciations, business investment growth, consumer borrowing growth, wealth increases, improved firm liquidity, debt deflation, bank multiplier changes ...

Is there accepted evidence for any of these actually happening in the US? What are the key references?